# Slider de imágenes automático sin fin

Tags: javascript, html, css

¿Alguién sabe alguna librería o cómo hacer este slider sin fin? , preferentemente sin usar jQuery.
La idea sería que las imágenes sean arrastrables y se muevan automáticamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Falta agregues el código que trabajas y el error o fallo que ocurre. "preferentemente sin usar jQuery" será bastante lo que necesitas escribir para lograr esos efectos.

Comment: Hay muchas por ahí, pero si quieres aprender puedes visitar https://javascript.espaciolatino.com/ejemplos/scripts/carruselimg.htm,  es un posible punto de partida para tu propio carrusel o puedes usarla tal cual.